# Calculate the slope of a straight line from experimental points

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

Draw a straight line from the experimental points so that the scatter of the experimental points is minimal. Having determined the slope of the resulting straight line.

How should I do it?
I understand what needs to be done according to the formula: (y2-y1) / (x2-x1).
But how do I calculate the minimum slope spread? And the maximum? What values should I take?
How can I do this without a graph?
Here is my graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7snfo0rl66

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because plotting and estimating the best straight line is a general skill in all sciences, maths, and other areas. It is not a physics question. It is also a skill best learned in-person.

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: You have 2-3 outliers in your data.  If possible, it would be helpful if you ran the experiment again and collected "cleaner" data, or find a way to explain the outliers.  Of course, if this is a homework problem, you can't do that, but you can use linear regression, as answered below.

Answer (score 1):

I think that linear regression through the least squares method is the mathematical tool that you need(I recommend googling it so you can understand it) but the idea of this method is finding the best line to fit your scattered data, with minimal deviation to the point of your graph

Answer (score 0):

You need to do what is called a "fit" i.e. a statistical procedure to find the best line describing all these points.

If you do that for a line you get that the angular coefficient $m$ is given by

$$m ={ \sum_i (x_i-X_i)(y_i-Y_i) \over \sum_i (x_i -X_i)^2}$$

where $(x_i, y_i)$ are your data points and $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are the average $x$ and $y$ values.

If you are a beginner, you should not use formulas you don't understand. So either check the derivation (maybe starting [here](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit)) or use one of the geometrical approaches (such as drawing a line containing the sane mnuber of points above and below it and compute its slope).

Answer (score 0):

The method is called **[linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression)**. There exist exact formulas to obtain the estimates for the slope, the y-offset and their uncertainties, see linked wiki article. However, nobody does the calculation by hand. Thus, it's best you learn one programming language. Here is the code in R, which is a free software specialized on statistics.

```
## Generate the dataset: This is where you place the actual data
x = seq(1, 10)
y = x + rnorm(length(x))

## plot the data:
plot(x,y) 

## fit the data:
df = data.frame(x=x, y=y)
lm.out = lm(y ~ x , df)

# display the result of the fit:
summary(lm.out)

> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)  0.88872    0.50624   1.756    0.117    
> x            0.96551    0.08159  11.834 2.38e-06 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> Residual standard error: 0.7411 on 8 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.946,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9392 
> F-statistic:   140 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 2.384e-06
```

Hence, the slope is given by $0.96    \pm 0.08$ and the $y$-offset by $0.88   \pm 0.50$. The other numbers are important as well, but I won't explain them here. Also make sure that you check the assumption of the fit to be valid:

```
# check the fit assumptions:
plot(lm.out)
```

Finally, it's always great to generate plesant plots:

```
## fancy way for plotting the result:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= y~x)
```

[image]